# Edit table data inline with DBVisualizer Free

Tags: dbvisualizer

I'm trying to edit table data in inline mode with DBVisualizer 9 Free version and i just can't. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible edit data using the free version, as it's display in the feature list (compare free and commercial versions) on SQL Editor.

http://www.dbvis.com/features/feature-list/